# WCF - can't get Identity.UserName inside service

Tags: wcf, authentication, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I'm trying to make a WP7 app which has to interact with WCF service.
What I want is to pass userName/password and see it in WCF service.

```
        Service1Client proxy = new Service1Client();
        proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName= "abc@email.com";
        proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "abc";
```

Code we tried in service to get authenticated name(but we got windows identity instead - MyPc\MyLogin)

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Here is client config

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <!--<security mode="None" />-->
              <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <!--<transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />-->                   
              </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:45148/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And here is server config

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <configuration>
           <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
          </system.web>
          <system.serviceModel>
            <behaviors>
              <serviceBehaviors >
                <behavior>
                  <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                  <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                  <serviceCredentials>
                    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                     customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WP7Service.WpfCustomValidator, WP7Service" />
                  </serviceCredentials>
                </behavior>
              </serviceBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
            <bindings>
              <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
                  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                  </security>
                </binding>
              </basicHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
            <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
          </system.serviceModel>
          <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
          </system.webServer>
        </configuration>
```

Also I have cutom username validator, but it is never called

```
    public class WpfCustomValidator :
      System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName == null || password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        var rf = WindsorAccessor.InitializeRepositoryFactory(userName);

        if (!ValidateLogOn(rf, userName, password))
        {
            throw new FaultException("Incorrect Username or Password");
        }
    }
}
```

I want the answer to show how to configure client and service to be able to see `ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName` in service via `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` or via current thread identity(or any other way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dominick Baier [shows you how do to do this](http://www.leastprivilege.com/HTTPBasicAuthenticationAgainstNonWindowsAccountsInIISASPNETPart3AddingWCFSupport.aspx) on his blog.

Your custom validator code does not get called because the service is configured for clientCredentialType="None" - i.e. no authentication.

Comment: Haven't tested yet, but seems it is what we need, tnx.

Comment: FYI - The link is now broken.